# nullptr read access violation while checking in loop

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

I have this code:

```
while (current->next->data <= temp->data && current->next != nullptr)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
```

when I run it i get the error:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
    current->next was nullptr.

I believe I should not be receiving this error because it is the exact thing I check for; I am new to this, is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the first expression that gets executed in the condition? Hint: It's not `current->next != nullptr` :)

Comment: That worked, Thank you.

Comment: So when you used your debugger, what did it tell you was null?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (current->next->data <= temp->data && current->next != nullptr)
```

This will fail for the very first iteration if `current->next` is `null`.
You should swap the order of condition check.

```
while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->data <= temp->data)
```

Answer (score 0):

By the
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical

> lhs && rhs
>
> For the built-in logical AND operator, the result is true if both operands are true. Otherwise, the result is false. This operator is short-circuiting: if the first operand is false, the second operand is not evaluated

The `lhs` expression will be executed first, so you should put your `current->next` null pointer check at the left side of `&&` in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Standard says [[expr.log.and]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.and)

> The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 7). The result is true if both
>   operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, **&& guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation**: the second operand is not evaluated if the
>   first operand is false.

So, in

```
current->next->data <= temp->data && current->next != nullptr
```

First evaluated first operand which is `current->next->data <= temp->data`. And here you have the error if `current->next` is `nullptr`.